# specify in place operation in a python function

Tags: python

Currently I have a python function that takes a numpy array and modifies it in place and I would like the user to be able to be able to choose this. So, currently, it is as:

```
def my_func(signal, filter):
    ...
    # Compute the filter weights
    signal *= filter
```

So I want to do something like:

```
def my_func(signal, filter, inplace=True):
   ...
   # Compute filter_weights
   if inplace:
       signal *= filter
   else:
       out = np.copy(signal)
       out *= filter
       return out
```

But the problem is that now we have one execution path that returns an output and the other which does not return anything. I am wondering if this is the correct approach or if there is a more pythonic way to do this.

Comment: You can have the in-place execution path return `signal`

Comment: It seems fine, you can call `var = my_func(...)` and then check `if var is None`...

Comment: This would probably be clearer as two functions. As done in the standard library, for example, with `list.sort` vs. `sorted`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and the tips. I guess I can take @tobias_k suggestion and return signal. I am guessing this will not cause a copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with your current version, if you do not want to provide two functions.

As an example, the Pandas library provides `sort` method for its container, that works as your example. If the sorting is done inplace, by providing the `inplace=True`, nothing is returned, otherwise a sorted copy is returned.